# screensaver not working and freezing the keyboard

Tags: xubuntu, screensaver

I'm currently encountering some issues with my screensaver.
I use Xubuntu 20.04 on a laptop Lenovo X270.
When I try to activate the screensaver using the screensaver interface in "parameters", nothing happens when I'm in the "presentation mode".
When I switch prensentation mode off, I still don't have a screensaver, but I can't type anything on keyboard, or click with the pad. I can still move the cursor though. But as I can click or type anything, the only exiting mode is to switch the PC off with the button.
Woudl you have any idea about this issue ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It does not solve the main problem but: Ctrl+Alt+F3 takes you to a terminal. Login and kill slock or screensaver or the application you think locked you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced very similar, all but the mouse freezing when locking the screen. So far, disabling the screensaver's embedded keyboard has been a success. Two ways to go about it, pretty sure they do the same thing:

- Open Screensaver preferences and make sure the On Screen Keyboard is disabled.
- In the Settings Editor find `xfce4-screensaver` on the left and `embedded-keybaord` at the top right, conveniently located directly under `Lock`. Clear the tick on the *nested* `enabled` box, as the other disables screen lock entirely.

( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> should provide the Application Finder; enter `xfce4-settings-editor` and launch to start)

Interesting to note the known issue list references the [embedded keyboard](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screensaver/start#known_issues) as being an issue:

> Allow embedding a keyboard into the window, /embedded-keyboard-enabled, may be non-functional. Onboard crashes when embedded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an old notebook in which I installed Xubuntu 20.04.  The screensaver had an odd behavior. It seemed to launch but nothing happened.  When moving the mouse pointer, nothing could be clicked, not even the keyboard was working.

I had to `ssh` to the computer and issue a `sudo reboot` (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> wasn't working too due to issues with the video driver). But it turns out to be something related to `xfce4-screensaver`. I simply uninstalled it using:

```
sudo apt remove xfce4-screensaver
```

and installed `xscreensaver`:

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

Hope it helps!